# Advice on running formula until max value

Tags: excel, max, survival-analysis

I am a grateful user of stack overflow – thanks to the community.

This is my first time posting.

I am creating individual-level life tables in excel and only need the command to run until a max possible age of 100.

I am using the excel command below. This, `($G7+I$6)` represents `age + time period`. Stating the obvious, this is not the output value but rather a component of the formula.

```
=EXP((-$C$2^-1)*(EXP($C$3+($D7*$F$2)+($C7*$F$3)+($B7*$F$4)))*(EXP($C$2*($G7+I$6))-1))
```

Once again, I need the formula to run until `($G7+I$6)` reaches 100.

How do I do this?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Jay

Comment: What do you wish to do after the value reaches 100? Not apply the formula to the next row?

Comment: When you say “the command”, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Hi Brad, my apologies. When I say 'command', I mean formula.

Comment: Hi Akshat, yes that's correct - stop the formula. I have columns so the formula should stop at the column where ($G7+I$6) reaches 100. But this is different for each individual.